# Why this function gave me the undefined in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am newbie to the javascript and I wrote the simple function below.
I am wonder that the function blow gave me the undefined. Is there any mistake in the function below?

```
function randFace() {
    return ["crown", "anchor", "heart", "spade", "club", "diamond"]
    [rand(0, 5)];
}

console.log(randFace())
```

Comment: Are you trying to use Math.random to get a random number from 0 to 5? If Yes, you can refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#getting_a_random_number_between_two_values

Comment: Can you add the definition of `rand` so other people can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
function randFace() {
    let faces = ["crown", "anchor", "heart", "spade", "club", "diamond"]
    return faces[Math.floor(Math.random() * faces.length)];
}

console.log(randFace())
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not clear what is the `rand` in your problem does.

Thus, in JavaScript, there is a function called [random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#getting_a_random_number_between_two_values) that generates a random number between 0 and 1.

To generate the random index for the given array we need to have values between **0 and 6**.

Since `Math.random` generated the value between **0 and 1**, we need to multiply that value with the `arr.length`.

```js
const arr = ["crown", "anchor", "heart", "spade", "club", "diamond"];
function randFace() {
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    
    return arr[rand];
    
}

console.log(randFace())
```

Answer (score 0):

Undefined error is occurring because there is **no rand() function**. i believe that you want to get a random string from the array using the function. I have altered your code little bit to get the expected output. Try it to see if this is what you want

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}
function randFace() {
    return ["crown", "anchor", "heart", "spade", "club", "diamond"]
    [getRandomInt(0, 5)];
}

console.log(randFace())
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple code using javscript

```js
    const value= ["crown", "anchor", "heart", "spade", "club", "diamond"]
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * value.length);
 console.log(value[random]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function randFace() {
var faces= ["crown", "anchor", "heart", "spade", "club", "diamond"]
return(faces[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)]);
}

console.log(randFace())
```

I think this is what you are looking for.:)

Answer (score 0):

`rand()` is an incorrect method in javascript.

You will get your desired output by the following code.

```
function randFace() {
    return ["crown", "anchor", "heart", "spade", "club", "diamond"]
    [Math.floor(Math.random()*5+1)];
}

console.log(randFace())
```

You can refer more about random in [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp).